# Where do i save windows universal user files?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

My problem is that I cant find any documentation about where i should save user files, The files will contain keys and values for example. Where is the file path, Because don't windows desktop and windows phone have different folders?

```
FirstName="James"
```

Do windows universal apps have something like

```
LocalStorage.LocalData("MyApp\properties.prop")
```

or anything similar? or should i use something like `"%appdata%\myapp\file.properties"` Is there any documentation somebody can link me to? or just explain what i should do?

Comment: If you need to save few keys then consider using roaming settings for better user experience across different range of devices.

Comment: This is a nice overview: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When choosing to save user data (p.e. settings values and other small in size data) in UWP you have 2 choices. Local and Roaming. 
You can get access to these via the `ApplicationData` class.

[Local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings)

```
var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings
```

[Roaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings)

```
var settings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings
```

and access the values like that

```
var myvalue = (MyClass)settings.Values["key"];
```

**Things to bear in mind:** 
As you will read in the documentation there are limits 
to how much data you can store in either container. Also if you exceed that limit for the roaming container it behaves like local storage. 
For larger files you can use LocalFolder and RoamingFolder but it is not as easy as simply accessing values like a dictionary.

Also in UWP there is the [PublisherCacheFolder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/09/11/uwp-publisher-cache.aspx) if that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking for a while i found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx)

It contained everything i was looking for.